# EXCEL VBA get source folder to Const

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, parameters

i have a code "copyMultFiles" Move many value in many file to single file
My Problem is cannot use parameter in "Const"

**Error this Line " Const csMyPath As String = vaFiles1 "**
vaFiles1 is get source folder i cannot input in csMypath

```
 'get source folder
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog
    Dim vaFiles1  As String
    ' Open the file dialog
    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show

    'MsgBox diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)
    vaFiles1 = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

    '    change these to suit requirements
    Const csMyPath As String = vaFiles1
    Const csMyFile As String = "*.xls" 'source search pattern
    Const csSRng As String = "$B$5,$G$36,$I$36,$G$37,$I$37" 'source range
    Const csTRng As String = "$A$1" 'target range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare a constant that isn't constant. You're setting a variable at run time, as such, you need to make this a variable.

```
Dim csMyPath As String: csMyPath = vaFiles1
```